# How to find all available systems?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp, asdf

There are good functions I use to study Common Lisp projects:

```
CL-USER> (list-all-packages)
CL-USER> (describe (asdf:find-system "asdf"))
```

How to list all systems know for `asdf`, `quicklisp` or `sbcl`?
I've tried to dig it from documentation but did not find it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All systems registered in ASDF:

```
(asdf:registered-systems)
```

I found that one by typing `asdf:systems` and letting auto-completion suggests a name. The symbol is exported, so it is fair game. Apparently it is undocumented.

Quicklisp has a notion of distributions, *dists*.

```
(ql-dist:all-dists)
```

Each dist has different versions (http://blog.quicklisp.org/2011/08/going-back-in-dist-time.html):

```
(ql-dist:available-versions (ql-dist:dist "quicklisp"))
```

Each dist provides systems:

```
(ql-dist:provided-systems (ql-dist:dist "quicklisp"))
```

Each system has a release, you can list all releases:

```
(ql-dist:provided-releases (ql-dist:dist "quicklisp"))
```

Conforming implementation have a list of [`*MODULES*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_module.htm), which is useful notably for systems that are available as built-ins by your implementation; for SBCL:

```
CL-USER> (require 'sb-mpfr)
("SB-MPFR" "SB-GMP")

CL-USER> *modules*
("SB-GMP" "SB-MPFR" ...)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to doc for `(asdf:registered-systems)`  there is nothing in manual https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Function-and-Class-Index

Comment: @Hellseher I updated the answer, sorry the function is undocumented AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use to have a convenient search through all quickdist's systems, lookup their documentation and dependencies:

http://quickdocs.org

Comment: Thanks, I aware of that source. I'm just building up my tool box of build it functions/variables for studding projects and learning CL. dnf/apt/dpkg/rpm etc. utils for packages on GNU/Linux distributions